# How to show two plots with different axes?

Tags: plotting, graphics, charts, histograms, overlay

What is the easiest way to plot something like

[image]

where either x-y axes pair is independent of the other. I tried combining `BarChart` and `ListPlot`, but with no success, as the scaling really messes everything up. Any ideas? I have heard about `MultiaxisArrangement`, but I am not too sure how that would work with a bar chart.

Here is a working example:

```
plot1 = BarChart[{1, 2, 3, 4}, 
  ChartLabels -> 
   Placed[{"data1", "data2", "data3", "data4"}, Below, 
    Rotate[#, Pi/2] &], ChartStyle -> "Pastel", 
  AxesLabel -> {None, None}, BarSpacing -> 0.2, AspectRatio -> .5, 
  ImageSize -> 300, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> "Number of data", 
  GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> Directive[LightGray]] 

dataPoints = {{1997, 9}, {1998, 14}, {1999, 12}, {2000, 17}, {2001, 
    17}, {2002, 28}, {2003, 21}, {2004, 16}, {2005, 30}, {2006, 
    29}, {2007, 31}, {2008, 37}, {2009, 42}, {2010, 62}, {2011, 
    56}, {2012, 61}, {2013, 54}, {2014, 82}, {2015, 72}, {2016, 
    76}, {2017, 79}, {2018, 75}, {2019, 58}, {2020, 79}, {2021, 
    78}, {2022, 80}, {2023, 60}};

plot2 = ListPlot[dataPoints, PlotStyle -> {Black}, 
  PlotMarkers -> {"\[FilledSquare]", 10}, Axes -> False, 
  Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {{None, "Number of events"}, {None, "Year"}}, 
  FrameTicks -> {{None, All}, {None, All}}, AspectRatio -> .5]
```

[image]

Comment: Can it be deduced that the number of papers (shown in red) is declining every year? Or that there are many events happening in toxicology compared to physics?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use [ResourceFunction["CombinePlots"]](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/CombinePlots/)

```
combinePlots = ResourceFunction["CombinePlots"];

bc = BarChart[{1, 2, 3, 4}, 
   ChartLabels ->  
     Placed[{"data1", "data2", "data3", "data4"}, Below, Rotate[#, Pi/2] &], 
   ChartStyle -> "Pastel", 
   BarSpacing -> 0.2, 
   AspectRatio -> .5, 
   Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> {None, "Number of Data"}, 
   GridLines -> Automatic, 
   GridLinesStyle -> Directive[LightGray], 
   ImageSize -> 800];

lp = ListPlot[dataPoints, 
   PlotStyle -> Black, 
   PlotMarkers -> {"■", 10}, 
   Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> {"Year", "Number of Events"}, 
   FrameTicks -> All, 
   AspectRatio -> .5];


combinePlots[bc, lp, "AxesSides" -> "TwoXY"]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, kglr, I updated my answer

Answer (score 6):

```
plot1 =
 BarChart[{1, 2, 3, 4}, 
  ChartLabels -> 
   Placed[{"data1", "data2", "data3", "data4"}, Below, Rotate[#, Pi/2] &], 
  ChartStyle -> "Pastel", 
  AxesLabel -> {None, None}, 
  BarSpacing -> 0.2, 
  AspectRatio -> .5, 
  Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> "Number of data", 
  GridLines -> Automatic, 
  GridLinesStyle -> Directive[LightGray], 
  ImagePadding -> 50,
  ImageSize -> 800];

plot2 = 
 ListPlot[dataPoints, 
  PlotStyle -> {Black}, 
  PlotMarkers -> {"\[FilledSquare]", 10}, 
  Axes -> False, 
  Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {{None, "Number of events"}, {None, "Year"}}, 
  FrameTicks -> {{None, All}, {None, All}}, AspectRatio -> .5, 
  ImagePadding -> 50,
  ImageSize -> 800];

Overlay[{plot1,plot2}]
```

[image]

**Addendum**

As kglr commented you can use `Overlay[{plot1, plot2}, All, 2]` to get tooltips for the black data points.

Comment: Interesting, but it seems I need to manually adjust the padding value, right? Is there a way of making this automatic?

Comment: I don't think so. I always do it manually with these `Overlay` - plots. It doesn't take too long.

Comment: Just one more question, is it possible to set the padding of the final object to be automatically tight?

Comment: The tightest would be `ImagePadding -> 31`. But you have to set it manually for both plots. I don't know an automatic way to find the `31`.

Comment: (+1) You can retain interactive highlighting of `plot2` using `Overlay[{plot1, plot2}, All, 2]`.